# Clickable thumbnail image in a tooltip

Tags: java, image, swing, tooltip, clickable

I would like to have a special sort of tooltip appear when a user hovers the mouse cursor over a specific item in a treetable. This tooltip will be a thumbnail of a PDF that corresponds to the item in the treetable that the cursor is pointing at. In addition, I'd like the user to be able to then move the cursor over the thumbnail and click it, which should open up the full PDF in their system's default PDF reader (Acrobat, Adobe Reader, etc.).

I realize this is a tall order, but I've already done most of the work. I've discovered exactly where in my huge program that I need to have the `setToolTip()` method so that it can retrieve the appropriate thumbnail. In addition, since I've discovered that having Java create thumbnails from a PDF on the fly is far too difficult, I've already got things set up so there will be thumbnail JPGs pre-made. Thus, all the `setToolTip()` command will need to do is somehow retrieve the appropriate JPG. Now comes the hard part.

At first, it seemed easy. I tried [this really convenient hack for putting an image in a tooltip](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/how-to-use-images-in-tooltips-2.html), and it definitely gets the thumbnail showing up properly. However, surrounding the `<img>` tag with an anchor tag (`<a href="...">...</a>`) doesn't quite seem to work. The thumbnail is surrounded by the tell-tale blue border, alright, but the image remains un-clickable. In addition, the tooltip sometimes just disappears before it's image can be clicked upon.

So I thought I might need to do something more deep than a simple html hack. I tried [this more involved way of putting an image in a tooltip](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ShowinganImageinaToolTip.htm), but it seems that will only work for a static image. I need the image to be different depending on what's being hovered over with the mouse cursor. In addition, how do I set my method to use this 'custom version of a tooltip' rather than the built-in one?

To give a bit more context, the location where the `setToolTip()` method seems to work is inside of a `getTreeCellRendererComponent()` method, a part of a custom class that extends `JPanel` and implements `TreeCellRenderer`. I'll post the code if asked, but it will might be rather complicated and hard to follow. Any thoughts?

**EDIT 10/09/2014, 4:57pm:** Much of this code may be confusing, and for that, I apologize. Suffice it to say that it has to do with putting a tri-state checkbox inside of a JXTreeTable. Anyway, the parts that are important should be easy enough to pick out, I hope. As you can see, this class already extends `JPanel`, so I cannot have it extend `JToolTip` as well.

```
package info.chrismcgee.sky.treetable;

import info.chrismcgee.beans.OrderDetail;
import info.chrismcgee.components.ImageToolTip;
import info.chrismcgee.components.TristateCheckBox;
import info.chrismcgee.components.TristateState;
import info.chrismcgee.enums.OSType;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolTip;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.treetable.DefaultMutableTreeTableNode;

public class SkyCheckTreeCellRenderer extends JPanel implements
        TreeCellRenderer {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2728513730497144120L;
    private SkyCheckTreeSelectionModel selectionModel;
    private TreeCellRenderer delegate;
    private boolean showRootNodeCheckBox;
    private TristateCheckBox checkBox = new TristateCheckBox("");
    protected SkyCheckTreeManager.CheckBoxCustomizer checkBoxCustomer;
    private String jobsFolderStr = OSType.getOSType() == OSType.MAC
            ? "/Volumes/ArtDept/ArtDept/JOBS"
            : "//SKYFS/ArtDept/ArtDept/JOBS";

    public SkyCheckTreeCellRenderer(TreeCellRenderer delegate,
            SkyCheckTreeSelectionModel selectionModel,
            boolean showRootNodeCheckBox) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.selectionModel = selectionModel;
        this.showRootNodeCheckBox = showRootNodeCheckBox;
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setOpaque(false);
        checkBox.setOpaque(false);
    }

    public JToolTip createToolTip() {
        return new ImageToolTip();
    }

    private String getToolTipText(DefaultMutableTreeTableNode node)
    {
        if (node.getUserObject() instanceof OrderDetail)
        {
            OrderDetail od = (OrderDetail) node.getUserObject();
            String thousandsFolderStr = jobsFolderStr + "/"
                    + od.getOrderId().substring(0, 3) + "000-"
                    + od.getOrderId().substring(0, 3) + "999/";

            String productFolderStr = thousandsFolderStr + od.getOrderId()
                    + " Folder/";
            if (!od.getProductDetail().equals(""))
                productFolderStr = thousandsFolderStr + od.getOrderId() + "/";

            String img = productFolderStr + od.getOrderId() + "_THUMB.jpg";
            if (!od.getProductDetail().equals(""))
                img = productFolderStr + od.getOrderId() + "_" + od.getProductDetail() + "_THUMB.jpg";

            if (new File(img).exists())
                return "<html><img src=\"file://" + img + "\"></html>";
        }
        return null;
    }

    public JComponent getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
            boolean hasFocus)
    {
        JComponent renderer = (JComponent) delegate.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
                selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);

        if (!showRootNodeCheckBox && tree.getModel().getRoot() == value)
        {
            renderer.setToolTipText(getToolTipText((DefaultMutableTreeTableNode)value));
            return renderer;
        }

        TreePath path = tree.getPathForRow(row);
        if (path != null) {
            if (checkBoxCustomer != null && !checkBoxCustomer.showCheckBox(path))
            {
                renderer.setToolTipText(getToolTipText((DefaultMutableTreeTableNode)value));
                return renderer;
            }
            if (selectionModel.isPathSelected(path, selectionModel.isDigged()))
                checkBox.getTristateModel().setState(TristateState.SELECTED);
            else
                checkBox.getTristateModel().setState(selectionModel.isDigged()
                        && selectionModel.isPartiallySelected(path)
                            ? TristateState.INDETERMINATE
                            : TristateState.DESELECTED);
        }
        removeAll();
        add(checkBox, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(renderer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setToolTipText(getToolTipText((DefaultMutableTreeTableNode)value));
        return this;
    }

}
```

I get that I need to *somehow* extend JToolTip, and that this SkyCheckTreeCellRenderer class needs to *somehow* reference that custom tooltip. I guess all of this is just getting so involved and complex that my simple brain is having trouble wrapping around it all. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

> how do I set my method to use this 'custom version of a tooltip' rather than the built-in one?

As the example shows you need to extend the component to use the custom tool tip.

> I need the image to be different depending on what's being hovered over with the mouse cursor

Then you will need to override the `getToolTipText(MouseEvent)` method to return a text string to represent the image you want to display.

> However, surrounding the  tag with an anchor tag (...) doesn't quite seem to work

You would need to use a JEditorPane if you want to respond to a hyperlink. Read the JEditorPane API for an example.

So basically I would suggest that you need to use a custom JToolTip, that uses a JEditorPane to display the appropriate Image with an appropriate Hyperlink. Here is an example that shows how to use a JLabel as an added component to a tool tip. You should be able to modify the code to use a JEditorPane.

Also, you need to extend your tree table to use this custom JToolTip.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ToolTipImage extends JToolTip
{
    private Image image;

    public ToolTipImage(Image image)
    {
        this.image = image;

        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        add( new JLabel( new ImageIcon( image) ) );
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(image.getWidth(this), image.getHeight(this));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() throws Exception
    {
        final BufferedImage testImage = ImageIO.read(new File("dukewavered.gif"));

        String[] columnNames = {"Column 0", "Column 1"};

        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Cell 0,0", "Cell 0,1"},
            {"Cell 1,0", "Cell 1,1"}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)
        {
            public JToolTip createToolTip()
            {
                return new ToolTipImage( testImage );
            }
        };

        // Set tool tip text so that table is registered w/ tool tip manager
        table.setToolTipText(" ");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tool Tip Image");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new JScrollPane(table) );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                }
                catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I see where you're going with this, but the relevant class I have already extends `JPanel`. See my edit to understand where I'm coming from. Any ideas, @camickr or @ControlAltDel?

Comment: @Sturm `As you can see, this class already extends JPanel, so I cannot have it extend JToolTip as well.` I never said you had to extend JToolTip as well. In the example I gave you the `ToolTipImage` class is a separate class.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to build a custom tooltip, as [detailed in JToolTip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolTip.html).

When clicked, you should use Runtime to open your file from the commandline. The way to do this in windows is posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/550138/open-file-with-default-application-from-command-line). The way to do this on ubuntu is posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15354/how-to-open-file-with-default-application-from-command-line)